# LD_LIBRARY_PATH не работает загрузка динамической библиотеки

Tags: linux, mono

При старте консольного приложения устанавливаю переменной среды окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` текущую директорию, откуда запускаю приложение

```
    string LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH";
    string currentPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV)))
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV, currentPath);
    }
    else
   {
       Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV, currentPath + ":" + (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV)));
   }
   logger.Debug(string.Format("Current LD_LIBRARY_PATH: {0}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ENV)));
```

В логах вижу, что переменная установилась успешно. Далее, с помощью функции `dlopen`, объявленная следующим образом

```
[DllImport("libdl.so")]
public static extern IntPtr dlopen(string filename, int flags);
```

пытаюсь загрузить динамическую библиотеку(`.so`), находящуюся в текущей директории приложения. 
Функция возвращает 0, то есть библиотека не загрузилась. 
Если я скопирую эту библиотеку в папку `/lib`, то библиотека успешно загружается. 
Согласно этой статье [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/), поиск нативной библиотеки он должен начинать с директорий, определенных в переменной `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Система Kubuntu 15.10.
Как правильно определять переменную `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` под Mono?